# Mysql Not Working When Inserting via Bash Commands, but Working When Inserted Manuall

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, sql-insert

So I am working with an mysql database that is on aws(Amazon web services) and I have found that there seems to be a problem when I added it a Parameter Group to it.

Without the Parameter Group I can use this in a bash script and it will insert it into the correct table

```
mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw <<QUERY_INPUT
use glacier;
insert into test values ('anna');
QUERY_INPUT
```

With the Parameter Group the above part does not work , yet I can manually log in and insert the values I want.

Has anyone had any problems like this before?

FYI it has nothing to do with the security group, the database was in the same security group before I added the new Parameter Group to it.

Comment: Okay, so what parameters does the parameter group change?  And what does "does not work" mean?  Nothing happens?  Errors?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Nothing happens and a lot autocommit = 0, character_set_server = utf8, collation_server = utf8_general_ci, event_scheduler = ON, innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2097152,innodb_buffer_pool_size = DBInstanceClassMemory, innodb_file_per_table = 1. innodb_log_buffer_size = 8388608, key_buffer_size = 16777216, log_output = TABLE, lower_case_table_names = 1, max_connections = DBInstanceClassMemory, read_buffer_size = 262144, read_only = TrueIfReplica, read_rnd_buffer_size = 524288, thread_stack = 262144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after going over some more documentation I found that mysql has a commit call and that you can turn auto commit off and I found in the Parameter Group that it has auto-commit off. So for anyone who might need this my code now looks like

```
mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw <<QUERY_INPUT
use glacier;
insert into test values ('anna');
commit;
QUERY_INPUT
```

Thank you guys for trying to help

Comment: Unless you turned `autocommit` off for a reason, you might not want to set it that way in your parameter group.  The default value is 1 and there may be other code that expects it to be that way.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the company that I work for wants it off because so I am just working with what they want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password-$mysqlpasswd << END
use glacier;
SELECT * from table_name;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your DB Instance as a member to the Parameter Group

Comment: When it is a member of the Parameter Group is when I have the problem and when it not it works perfectly